# OOP Java. Error while trying to implement an abstract method

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

So, here is a piece of my abstract class:

```
abstract public void insert(Object obj);
```

And here is the implementation in a class that extends it:

```
public void insert(User u){
    try{
        String sql = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE + " (username, assword) VALUES ("+u.getUsername()+", " +u.getPassword()+")";
        conn.execSQL(sql);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }finally{
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

and Here is the error:

*The type --- must implement the inherited abstract method ---.insert(Object) userDAO.java*

Basically, it is saying to me that I didn't implement any method that is called "insert" and receives an object as parameter. Doesn't my model "User" count as an object? What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for your attention.

Ps.: error message on Eclipse while developing an Android App (I don't know if it changes anything).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method signature is incorrect, base and derived methods take different objects. Let me try and explain:

Assume you have a class Base which takes an instance of another class B1 in one of its methods (say m1). Also assume that you have a Derived class Derived1 which *overrides* the method (m1) in Base with the parameter D1 and similarly a derived class Derived2 which overrides the base method with parameter D2.

Both D1 and D2 implement/extend B1. This will be a problem because of the following scenario:

```
Base baseObj = new Derived1();
baseObj.m1(new D2()); // Should work if it is allowed to override a method in your way!
```

The above code snippet fails because the m1 method in Derived1 expects a parameter of type D1, but it got D2. Do you now see why this type of parameter casting is not permitted?

Note: It is a good practice to use @override annotation when overriding a method in base (from Java 1.5 specification)

Comment: I sort of had to read it like 4 times, but I got your point. Awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about not being verbose, but glad that it helped you.

Comment: It's not possible to talk about those sorts of concepts without being verbose. Excellent explanation, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the method signatures,

```
void insert(Object obj);
```

and

```
void insert(User u)
```

are not the same, so you are not fulfilling the contract.

Comment: true but user is also object.

Comment: but not every object is a user. ;]

Answer (score 2):

The method signature must match *exactly*. This includes the method name (ok), the return type (ok) and the parameter types (not ok.)

It doesn't matter that `User` must inherit from `Object`, they both explicitly need to be the same type. Think about it - otherwise someone could call your method with an `Object` which isn't a `User`, then the subclass would have no way of knowing how to deal with that parameter.

If you only want someone to call your method with `User` objects, and calling it with any other type would be an error, you may do something like this:

```
public void insert(Object o) {
    if(o instanceof User) {
        //Normal behaviour
    }
    else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Object must be of type user!");
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the instanceof tip.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the method signatures are *not* the same - the abstract method takes `Object`, but the implementation takes `User`.

However, if you want to implement such a pattern, try generics:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass<T> {

    abstract public void insert(T t);

}


public class MyImpl extends MyAbstractClass<User> {

    public void insert(User t) {
        // compiles OK
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The overriding method must have the header `public void insert(Object obj)` (example: try overriding the `equals` method of a class). You can always cast your argument within the method body.

Answer (score 0):

That is because your abstract method insert has a parameter of type Object, which boils down to java.lang.Object and your attempt to implement the method has a User type supplied as a parameter. Your abstract method should use a generic type